# Posting an element to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, leveldb

I need add a user with role + pass to leveldb. And this is the code for the added item:

```
$scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.username;
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/addUser',
        key: {
            username: $scope.username,
            params: {
                value: {
                    password: $scope.password,
                    role: $scope.role
                }
            }
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        $scope.getAllItems();
    }).catch((reason) => {
        console.log(reason);
    })
};
```

How make the structure in the controller? Console returned :

> [WriteError: put() requires a key argument]

Comment: Is this the part of the code that is throwing the error ? Any line information in the error ? Also, I'm not really sure to understand what you want to do, I guess it's some part of a bigger project, can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: I want to insert a user in a level database. This is a part of the code of the controller in angular and url: '/addUser', is the url to model for insert a new user. [WriteError: put() requires a key argument] it is refers that the model need the key for the level database. The problem is that the structure in angular controller is not the way. In model I have this: context.db.put(username, { password,role }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`key` is not a valid `$http` param. You have to use `data` key to set your object in your request body :

```
$http({
    method:'POST',
    url:'/addUser',
    data:{
        username:$scope.username,
        password: $scope.password,
        role: $scope.role
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the model. /adduser

```
module.addUser =  (username, password, role) => {
    return new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => {
        context.db.open ();
               context.db.put(username,
              {
                password,
                role
              },
               (err) =>{
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            }
            else {
              context.db.close ();
              resolve({role: role, password: password});
              console.log(password, role);
            }
          });
        });
      }
```